# Is there any other NoSQL database that support transactions like Redis?

Tags: transactions, nosql

I've been looking for something like [redis transactions](http://redis.io/topics/transactions) in a few other NoSQL databases but I couldn't find something similar. I'm aware of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2212230/transactions-in-nosql) which does have some valid point of views, but without getting very deep of the reasons of my question, am I overlooking this feature in another NoSQL db?

Answer (score 5):

[FoundationDB](http://foundationdb.com/) is a NoSQL key-value store that supports ACID transactions.

Comment: And provides very nice Python API

Comment: Also can be expanded over multi-node clusters.

Answer (score 2):

Neo4J has ACID transactions. It's a [graph database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_database) instead of a key-value store, but still gets categorized as NoSQL.

http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/transactions.html

Answer (score 0):

ZODB

http://www.zodb.org/

http://www.zodb.org/documentation/guide/transactions.html?highlight=transaction

Answer (score 0):

The world of NoSQL is very vast and there are many NoSQL solution that offers transactions capabilities.  The one I know best is [GT.M](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fis-gtm/), which implements full support for ACID (Atomic, Consistent, Isolated, Durable).