# Transactional NoSQL with scalability & replication

Tags: transactions, nosql, sharding

Are there any transaction supported NoSqls out there? We know RavenDB is one such product, but its licensing seems to be expensive.

We would like to know if there are any good and cost-effective(free will also be a good option :).

I have had a look at other threads like [Transactions in NoSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2212230/transactions-in-nosql) and they seem pretty old. I believe some fresh updates will be good.

Comment: Yes, [there are a few](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_structured_storage_software).

Comment: Good one. Are there any .Net Client supported ones? My Google search cannot reveal some good one with all the above for .Net clients..