# Do transactions happen only in SQL database in Spring Boot projects?

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, transactions, nosql

I'm learning about SQL and NoSQL databases in Spring Boot projects. And I have a question about transactions in databases. I know that when you use @Transactional at a method, all the queries from that method are taken as a single transaction and if there is no exception when that method is executed all the changes will be committed to database, otherwise the changes will be rolled back.  What I want to know is if that thing is happen only if I use an SQL database? Do they happen in a NoSQL database as well. From what I know ACID is only for SQL databases. Thank you!

```
@Transactional
public void businessLogic() {
 // create customer resource
 // update customer resource
 // other create/update
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any NoSQL data store that is ACID compliant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2608103/is-there-any-nosql-data-store-that-is-acid-compliant)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Transactions in NoSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2212230/transactions-in-nosql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I want to know is if that thing is happen only if I use an SQL database?

Yes.

You described the behaviour which is primarily associated with SQL databases, and it does not apply uniformly to all NoSQL databases.

> Do they happen in a NoSQL database as well. From what I know ACID is only for SQL databases.

NoSQL databases typically do not support ACID transactions in the same way as SQL databases. If you switch to a NoSQL database, you may need to handle transactions differently. You need to consider the specific transaction support of a particular database.